Unable to set up swagger with spring boot 3
I am trying to setup swagger with spring boot.
Here is my java version:
> java --version
openjdk 23 2024-09-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 23+37-2369)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23+37-2369, mixed mode, sharing)

Here is my pom.xml:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mahesha999</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-postgres</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

  <properties>
    <java.version>23</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>

When I hit following URLs:
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/
http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs

I get whitelabel error page, something like this:

I tried some other swagger dependencies available online with no luck. How can I make swagger UI work with my java and spring boot version? Or do I need to change my java and / or spring boot verions themselves? Do I need to specify context-path as specified here?

what about properties, did you set springdoc there ? and did you set swagerConfig bean ?

nope nothing else ... I recall some years back, I just added the dependency and it started working. Also the official doc says: "No additional configuraiton is needed." Online some tutorials say the same, while other require some configurations.

Then please check my answer, i added a suggestion, and please let me know if it works.

It's not reproduceable on my local. I took your pom.xml for testing. I tried with JDK 21 as I had that JDK only. It's working. But it should work for JDK 23 as well.

Suggestion: Create a sample project and add that pom.xml and test it step - by - step.

Otherwise, provide your codebase for testing.

@AnishB. So you created simple maven project and just added my pom?

@MsA Yes. I have done that.

Thanks @AnishB. I downgraded to JDK 21 (extracted jdk21 zip and set JAVA_HOME and PATH) and it started working without any extra changes !

@MsA Can I add this answer?:)

Sure, please do it ...

There is no issue I see.
It's not reproduceable on my local. I took your pom.xml for testing.
I tried with JDK 21 as I had that JDK only on my machine. It's working fine as expected.

Then you should try this :
in application.yml
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /v3/api-docs
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger-ui.html

or in application.properties:
springdoc.api-docs.path=/v3/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html

then create this bean :
import org.springdoc.core.GroupedOpenApi;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi publicApi() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .group("springshop-public")
                .pathsToMatch("/api/**")
                .build();
    }
}

and retry again.

Thanks for suggestion. However, I downgraded to JDK 21 (extracted jdk21 zip and set JAVA_HOME and PATH) and it started working without any extra changes !
